# Get the values from three different array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have three different arrays

```
price = Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => 300
    [2] => 400
    [3] => 500
)

package = Array
(
    [0] => 100040
    [1] => 100041
    [2] => 100042
    [3] => 100043
)

NoOfClients =Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 400
    [3] => 750
)
```

In need to get package and price based on NoOfClients .
Example: If i have client count is 350, So my package is 100042 and price = 400.
For more understand below i show one if else condition

```
clients = 350;
if(clients <= NoOfClients[0]){

plan = 100040
price = 200

}elseif(clients > NoOfClients[0] and clients <= NoOfClients[1]){

plan = 100041
price = 300

}elseif(clients > NoOfClients[1] and $clients <= NoOfClients[2]){

plan = 100042
price = 400

}else{

plan = 100043
price = 500

}
```

My question is how i will get the dynamic result(plan and price) based on three different arrays and passing client count. Please help

Comment: Can you confirm whether all the arrays have the same number of records?  i.e., if price has 4 records means, another 2 arrays also have 4 records only?

Comment: Yes. All three arrays have same number of records. note: i made edit in my post please re-look. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$clients = 10;

$i = -1;
foreach($NoOfClients as $item) {
   $i++;
   if ($clients < $item) break;
}

echo $plan = $package[$i];
echo $price = $price[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you are giving the array values in the ascending order like the same that you gave here, it is working fine

```
$clients= 10;
$price = array(200, 300, 400, 500);
$package = array(100040, 100041, 100042, 100043);
$NoOfClients = array(100, 200, 400, 750);

if($clients<=$NoOfClients[0])
{
    $tempprice=$price[0];
    $temppackage=$package[0];
}
else
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($NoOfClients);$i++)
    {
        if($i+1<=count($NoOfClients) && !$clients>=$NoOfClients[$i] && $clients<=$NoOfClients[$i+1])
        {
            $tempprice=$price[$i+1];
            $temppackage=$package[$i+1];
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $tempprice=$price[count($NoOfClients)-1];
            $temppackage=$package[count($NoOfClients)-1];
        }
    }
}

echo '<b>Price:</b> '.$tempprice.'<br/><b>Package:</b> '.$temppackage;
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `$clients` is less than `$NoOfClients[0]` (100)

Comment: Ok ok.. I missed the first condition.. I will edit the code now

Comment: @Bibin - can clients be a value less than 100?

Comment: Yes. This is not working $client is less than $NoOfClients[0] (100) and greater than $NoOfClients[2] (400).

Comment: Yes less than 100 also

Comment: @sujivasagam last loop in not working. I mean if the $client is greater than 400, it return first package (price[0]) and package (package[0]) values

Comment: @Bibin No i got the correct value. I checked with clients as 500. It returns Price: 500 and Package: 100043

Comment: Please share the possible values that you can check and the values that you are expecting

Comment: @sujivasagam your code is working properly. Thankyou for helping me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simply 4 values alone in the arrays then you can just get the values of price and package using the loop that you are using itself with small changes

```
clients = 350;
if(clients <= NoOfClients[0]){

plan = package[0];
price = price[0];

}elseif(clients > NoOfClients[0] and clients <= NoOfClients[1]){

plan =  package[1];
price = price[1];

}elseif(clients > NoOfClients[1] and $clients <= NoOfClients[2]){

plan =  package[2];
price = price[2];

}else{

plan =  package[3];
price = price[3];

}
```